# Second async method is not executed from specified scope if first execution threw exception

Tags: kotlin, async-await, coroutine

I am trying to achieve is to have UI, IO and DEFAULT CoroutineScope within my BaseActivity activity. Then use these scopes for some operations.

Everything seems to work fine unless exception is thrown inside suspendCoroutine {}.

If no exception is thrown I can use ioScope multiple times without no problems. But if exception is thrown in Response.ErrorListener and I call loginAsync(), async won't be executed and coroutine will stuck at userDeferred.await().

I checked ioScope.isActive flag. Before Exception was thrown flag was set to true. After exception was thrown flag is set to false and I can exception in was thrown in scope.

I found that when I use instead of ioScope.async{ } function withContext(ioScope.coroutineContext){} exception will not break scope and it can be used again.

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue. I could not find any help in documentations nor in blogs.

**BaseActivity**
CoroutineScopes creation.

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val ioJob = Job()
private val defaultJob = Job()
private val uiJob = Job()

protected val ioScope: CoroutineScope
    get() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + ioJob)
protected val uiScope: CoroutineScope
    get() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + uiJob)
protected val defaultScope: CoroutineScope
    get() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default + defaultJob)


    final override fun finish() {
        super.finish()

        uiJob.cancel()
        defaultJob.cancel()
        ioJob.cancel()
        getActivityTransitions().setFinishActivityTransition(this)
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**
Usage of ioScope from BaseActivity.

```
@Throws(LoginException::class)
suspend fun loginAsync(loginData: LoginData, context: Context): Deferred<User> {
    return ioScope.async {
        suspendCoroutine<User> { continuation ->
            val jsonObjectRequest = HttpClient.createJsonObjectRequest(
                "/users/me2",
                loginData.toJsonString(),
                Response.Listener {

                    val httpResponse : HttpResponse<User> = it.toString().jsonToObject()

                    continuation.resume(httpResponse.response)
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {
                    continuation.resumeWithException(LoginException(it))
                }
            )
            HttpClient.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
        }
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity**

```
private suspend fun performLogin() {
    val loginData = LoginData(login_username_text_input.value.toString(), login_password_text_input.value.toString())

    val userDeferred = UserServerRepository(ioScope).loginAsync(loginData,this@LoginActivity);

    try {
        val result = userDeferred.await()

        login_username_text_input.value = result.company

        //HomeActivity.startActivity(this@LoginActivity)
        //finish()
    }catch (loginException: LoginException){
        login_username_text_input.value = loginException.message
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity button setup**

```
loginButton.main_button.setAsyncSafeOnClickListener(uiScope, suspend {
        performLogin()
    })
```

**setAsyncSafeOnClickListener implemetation**

```
fun View.setAsyncSafeOnClickListener(uiScope: CoroutineScope, action: suspend () -> Unit) {
    val safeClickListener = SafeClickListener {
        uiScope.launch {
            isEnabled = false
            action()
            isEnabled = true
        }
    }

    setOnClickListener(safeClickListener)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you have to use `SupervisorJob()` instead of `Job()` if you want to have robust scopes.

Long answer: here is great article about how error handling in coroutine scopes works https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutine-job-hierarchy-finish-cancel-and-fail-2d3d42a768a9